# Using two Internet connections at the same time

Tags: windows-7, internet, internet-connection, bandwidth, pppoe

Recently I got a second Internet connection. Each connection has 50mpbs capacity. One of them is directly connected to my laptop via PPPoE (with username and password); the second one is Wi-Fi from the router. I would like to "merge" the traffic so I can have a more stable connection and download via utorrent/etc faster. I'm using Windows 7. I've added the RandomAdapter key in the registry. I've also tried to set the Interface metric of both connections to 1, but this doesn't seem to have any effect. Here is a cosmetically edited image of the Networking tab of Task Manager:

[image]

(the unadulterated image is [here](http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/5530/14780876.png)).

Can you suggest what to do or what software I should use? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

TCP/UDP only allow 1 IP address per endpoint.  Everything over the Internet that's meaningful from your point of view uses and assumes TCP or UDP.

Can you use something other than TCP/UDP that does work with multiple IPs?  Sure, if both sides agree.

For example, if you and a friend wanted to trade streams of data over multiple public IPs using servers and routers you 100% control, you could use [bondcat](https://github.com/benjojo/bondcat).

- Can you make it so someone who isn't using bondcat uses it?  No.

You can control what's on your end, but you can't control what's on every other server on the Internet - everyone's mostly for better or worse settled on TCP-based stuff with UDP here and there.

The way it's solved in the business world these days is through SD-WAN - SD-WAN is both a router that has ports for multiple ISP connections and is also a *service* - the SD-WAN device basically relegates ISP connections for one purpose - a private VPN-like tunnel to an upstream SD-WAN service.  Everything leaving or entering the site will go through the SD-WAN service.  Then, the provider service appears on the public Internet for you, and load balances or fails over communication back through your ISP connections to your site as appropriate.

A service for a non-business situation that does something similar is [Speedify](https://speedify.com/).  I've never used this, but heard about it after reading about [a guy in Australia who uses this service to use any or all of 6 ISP connections on his van](https://ghuntley.com/internet/).

You could probably do something on your own with a cloud VPS and appropriate setup on a Linux virtual machine.

Without something like the above setup, the best you can do is have some connections go over one ISP, and some connections go over another ISP.  You could, with the right firewall/routing setup, have all your torrent traffic use one ISP and all non-torrent traffic use another.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the following: http://www.connectify.me/dispatch/

It's not a brilliant solution, but does improve overall speed.

---

**Edit:**

The software allows to choose how the traffic is balanced over the adapters, such as dominate on latency or round robin the adapters equally.

Any software you get will only increase speeds where there is multiple connections to the server such as multi-threaded downloads or torrents for example.

For an improved overall network / internet speed 'bonded' network adapters or internet would be required to get a combined speed as such.

Theoretically Windows 7 or newer is supposed to balance between adapters by itself although I've found on various devices it can be more biased towards WiFi as shown in your image

Comment: Can you summarize why that website/program would be a good solution for the user's issue? As a link by itself, it may be seen as spam and potentially deleted

Comment: The software allows to choose how the traffic is balanced over the adapters, such as dominate on latency or round robin the adapters equally.
Any software you get will only increase speeds where there is multiple connections to the server such as multi-threaded downloads or torrents for example.

For an improved overall network / internet speed 'bonded' network adapters or internet would be required to get a combined speed as such.

Theoretically windows 7 is supposed to balance between adapters by itself although i've found on various devices it can be wifi heavy as shown in your image.

Comment: Please edit your answer with that information

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not support multiple gateways addresses for an individual machine, so i do not beleive that you can connect two different WAN routers, irrespective of cable or wifi.

However there may be another way; pfSense is a FREE firewall appliance operating system you can install on a small PC. It apparently supports multiple WAN links, so you could install PFSense onto a small computer with at least three network ports, connect your two routers to the WAN ports on the pfSense PC, connect the third LAN port of the PFSense to your LAN and let pfSense combine both connections.

https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Multi-WAN